# SPARQL code missing individuals from classes that are not subclasses

Tags: sparql

I am currently working on a sparql query that computes every individual and the class that the individual exists in. Here is an (awful) example of what my ontology looks like:

```
Owl:Thing
  -Lion    
  -Elephant    
  -Pets
      -Dog
      -Cat
```

Where `Lion` and `Elephant` are classes with no subclasses and `Dog` and `Cat` are subclasses of the class `Pet`. When I run my code, I got the individuals from `Dog` and `Cat`, but no individuals from `Lion` or `Elephant`.

```
SELECT ?indiv ?class
WHERE {    
        ?class rdf:type owl:Class .    
        ?indiv rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .    
        ?indiv rdf:type ?class    
} ORDER BY ?class ?indiv
```

So basically, the result of my code are the individuals that come from only classes that are subclasses, when I am expecting to have the individuals from all classes. Could anyone please help?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting of my question. I am new here

Comment: It's not possible to tell what is wrong here just by the information you've given, there could be a number of reasons. It might be because, for example, `Lion` is not recognized as a `owl:Class`, or it might be because the individuals of `Lion` are not recognized as `owl:NamedIndividual`. Also: what tool do you use to execute your query? Is an (OWL) reasoner active? Can you show a sample of what your data (including the actual individuals) actually looks like? Try and construct a [mcve].

Comment: Jeen Broesktra is right, your query is very specific to the OWL serialization. Your query could be done in a more generic way if you use the RDF relevant triple pattern only, i.e. `SELECT ?indiv ?class
WHERE {    
        ?indiv rdf:type ?class    
} ORDER BY ?class ?indiv` - nevertheless, you can find out why your query is not working if you look into your data, ideally you save it in N-Triples or Turtle format first. I guess, you used Protege?